# Most Popular Items alternate row colors?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, branding

Is it possible to do alternate row coloring on the Most Popular Items web part?
Similar to in a list table?

[image]

Comment: simplest way is to add a calculated column and apply alternate row color

Comment: But this isn't a sharepoint list.

Comment: Find the display template and apply alternative row color in the template.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-display-templates